# Using environment dependent django settings inside fabric task

Tags: python, django, fabric

I'm trying to use the database configuration set on settings files to make a database dump using fabric.

There's more than one settings file, so I'd like to be able to do so based on the environment I choose.

by now, my task is like this

```
def dump_database():
    with cd('~/project_folder'), prefix(WORKON_VIRTUALENV):

        django.settings_module(env.settings)
        from django.conf import settings

        dbname = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
        dbuser = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
        dbpassword = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']

        fname = '/tmp/{0}-backup-{1}.sql.gz'.format(
            dbname,
            time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        )

        run('mysqldump -u %s -p=%s %s | gzip -9 /tmp/backup-%s.sql.gz' % (
            dbuser,
            dbpassword,
            dbname,
            fname))
```

But I'm getting an ImportError:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'project.settings.production'
```

I've tried to use shell_env() to set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE instead of django.settings_module(env.settings), with the same result.

I use a task to change the environment based on a environment dict:

```
def environment(name):
    env.update(environments[name])
    env.environment = name
```

This way, I want to be able to create a dump from multiple hosts like:

```
fab environment:live dump_database
fab environment:otherhost dump_database
```

Without having to reproduce database settings from all hosts on fabfile.

Comment: And how have you solved it? I have the same question, because I have production settings only on the production server (no locally or in repository).

Answer (score 1):

Importing your Django settings file in fabric is explained here.
http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.3/api/contrib/django.html

Quoting from the above link:

```
from fabric.api import run
from fabric.contrib import django

django.settings_module('myproject.settings')
from django.conf import settings

def dump_production_database():
    run('mysqldump -u %s -p=%s %s > /tmp/prod-db.sql' % (
        settings.DATABASE_USER,
        settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
        settings.DATABASE_NAME
    ))
```

Comment: Yes, I based what I did on that link. The problem is, I want to be able to use multiple settings (based on the env dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: I don't answer the question but offer a different solution

I had the same problem.. so I did custom .py script like that:

I created a file named dump_db.py (placed next to fabfile.py for example, that is on the remote machine)

```
import os
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf import settings


def dump_mysql():
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", SETTINGS_MODULE)
    DB_NAME = settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME']
    DB_USER = settings.DATABASES['default']['USER']
    DB_PASSWORD = settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD']

    dump_file_name = '{time}_{db_name}.sql'.format(
        time=datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d'),
        db_name=DB_NAME,
    )

    os.system('mysqldump -u {db_user} -p{db_password} {db_name} > {to_file}'.format(
        db_user=DB_USER,
        db_password=DB_PASSWORD,
        db_name=DB_NAME,
        to_file=dump_file_name,
    ))

    return dump_file_name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        SETTINGS_MODULE = sys.argv[1:].pop()
    except IndexError:
        SETTINGS_MODULE = 'project_name.settings'

    print dump_mysql()
```

As you see sys.argv[1:].pop() tries to take optional argument (the setting module in this case).

So in my fabfile:
    import os

```
from fabric.api import env, local, run, prefix, cd

.....

def dump():
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    with prefix('source {}bin/activate'.format(env.venv)), cd('{}'.format(env.home)):
        dumped_file = run('python dump_db.py {}'.format(env.environment)) # the optional argument given

    file_path = os.path.join(env.home, dumped_file)
    copy_to = os.path.join(current_dir, dumped_file)
    scp(file_path, copy_to)


def scp(file_path, copy_to):
    local('scp {}:{} {}'.format(env.host, file_path, copy_to))
```

where env.environment = 'project_name.settings.*env_module*'

And this is how I dump my DB and copy it back to me.

Hope it comes handy to someone! :)